# ¿Por qué resta a mi reputación cuando doy votos negativos en cola de revisión?

Tags: soporte

Me he encontrado que cuando doy votos negativos en las colas de revisión, también me resta en mi reputación y cuando reviso en el ícono de la copa, me arroja -1 por cada voto negativo que he dado, referenciando a la pregunta o respuesta a la cual le di dicho voto. ¿Por qué pasa esto? Alguna regla que yo no haya visto?

Comment: Eliminé la etiqueta s de tu pregunta. Supongo que la pusiste accidentalmente. Pero tu pregunta era la unica con esa etiqueta y (al menos yo) no le veia el significado. Si me equivoqué con mi edición, puedes demostrarmelo y me retractaré.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Qué sucede cuando voto negativo?
> Cuando votas negativo, estás empujando esa publicación hacia abajo en la página, así que será vista por menos gente. Votar negativo en las publicaciones no es algo que queramos que tomes a la ligera, por lo que no es gratuito.
>
> Los votos negativos quitan 2 de reputación al dueño de la publicación.
> Los votos negativos en las respuestas te quitan 1 de reputación a ti, el votante.
> Los votos negativos en las preguntas son libres. (¿Por qué?)
> Puedes votar 30 veces por día (UTC), además obtienes 10 votos adicionales solamente para las preguntas. (¿Por qué?)

Fuente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

El voto negativo está siendo controlado, para que la gente no abuse de este mismo.
SO como tal, penaliza el spam de esto, pero a todos nos cuesta algo votar negativo, dado que no es lo ideal al momento de dar una opinion.

Es lo que muchos opinamos de.. "No deberían poder votar negativo sin que alguien haya comentado"
Dado que si vas a un usuario novato, y solo votas negativo, sin decir que tiene malo, es contraproducente. Obvio, este es solo uno de muchos posibles casos.